# Status bar font changes in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uifont, uistatusbar

I have this weird issue, in iOS 7 my application `UIStatusBar` looks like that:

[image: ios7 status bar]

But in iOS 6.1 the `UIStatusBar` looks like that:

[image]

So, I know what is the problem, it's because I'm overriding `systemFontOfSize` and `boldSystemFontOfSize`:

```
#import "UIFont+SytemFontOverride.h"

@implementation UIFont (SystemFontOverride)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Bold" size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:fontSize];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

How can I override the system font without effect the `UIStatusBar` in iOS6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No No No!**

Don't use a category like that, it has unexpected behaviour, you should always namespace your category methods.

e.g.

```
@implementation UIFont (OKASystemFontOverride)

+ (UIFont *)oka_boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Bold" size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)oka_systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:fontSize];
}

@end
```

You must then explicitly set the font on any labels you have.

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont oka_systemFontOfSize:17.f];
```

Comment: more information on categories and collisons: http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/06/clash-of-the-categories.html

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what i'm going to do. I wanted to know if there is a way to fix it and make it stay like that.